# In collection view One item should be shown at a time in screen?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

In my project i have collection ,in which horizontal pagination is enabled, Every thing working fine but, when i scroll,particular cell item not fit entire cell,It show half image of previous cell item and half current Items, i need One item to fit the entire screen ??? Any suggestion are welcome

Here is the code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; {
    SingleItemCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"SingleItemCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell ConfigaureCollectionViewItem:self.totalCellItems[indexPath.row]]; return cell;
}

-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView )collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width - 20, self.bounds.size.height - 40);
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code its easy to understand.

Comment: As already stated, we can't really help you without seeing some code or your setup in IB.

Comment: - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    SingleItemCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"SingleItemCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell ConfigaureCollectionViewItem:self.totalCellItems[indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

Comment: -(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width - 20, self.bounds.size.height - 40);
    return size;
}

Comment: Above i posted my collection view data source methods and  In  ConfigaureCollectionViewItem Method: i m setting the image

Comment: Where do you set the pagination enabled? Also, you don't actually need to implement the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` delegate method as your size doesn't seem to vary between cells. You can simply set the  `self.layout.itemSize`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should be using `UIPageViewController` in stead of `UICollectionView`. From your question it seems that you are trying to mimic the behaviour of the former.

Comment: Ya i need same behavior as like page view controller but i need to use collection view .That is problem ..any Idea please suggest me..I m new to the ios programming

Comment: What exactly is the reason that you need a `UICollectionView`. I'm not saying that it isn't true, but I am curious to why this is.

Comment: Actually in my project I have table view controler which is base view controller. In each table view cell i have to use collection view. So In first Table view cell i need page view  controller behavoro for Collection view  and Other table view cells  i need collection View behavior

Comment: I m using same collection view inside a for every table view cell